# Загрузка из репозитория MNIST

Tags: нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение

хочу воспользоваться вот такой конструкцией, взял из интернета, fetch_mldata('MNIST original'). Для того, чтобы попробовать потренировать сеть для распознавания цифр, но постоянно получаю ошибку URLError: urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known

Подскажите, кто пользовался, может я что-то не так делаю, везде пишет именно так и так писал fetch_mldata('MNIST Original').

Comment: приведите полный `error traceback` и версии пакетов, которые вы используете

Comment: @MaxU Мой косяк, получилось загрузить, я с терминала в Kaggle грузил. А сейчас локально в Jupyter, все загрузилось, спасибо